# Is there any conflict for Member Class Object?

Tags: c#

```
public class MemberBAL : Members
{
    private Member_DAL member;

    public MemberBAL()
    {
        member = new Member_DAL(this);
    }

    public void MemberInfo()
    {
        try
        {

            member.GetMemberInfo();

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw new Exception("Connection Failed.");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code, at first glance, seems technically correct.

However, without any explanation of your problem, or *what* you're trying to achieve, that's about all I can say.